# Linux VM running much slower on Linux host than Windows

Tags: linux, windows, virtualbox

I've been using a Linux VM in a Windows host for a while and always had pretty reasonable speeds. Recently I decided to switch to using Linux as my daily driver, so I set up a dual boot and migrated my VM over. However, I've noticed Linux itself seems to run a little slower than Windows, and the Linux VM is painfully slow. Am I missing something?

System Info:

- Windows 10 (Latest Update)
- Kubuntu 19.10
- Kali 2019.2 VM (Virtualbox)
- i7-9700F CPU
- 32GB DDR4 RAM
- 1TB SSD (Windows)
- 500GB SSD Partition (Linux)
- GTX 1050Ti

Comment: Maybe the Linux SSD partition is not properly aligned? "Partition alignment"

Comment: @DanielF How could I check/resolve this?